# Get child record using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

This is my first time to hear about `LINQ` and I have no idea about it. Please be gentle on me.

I have this set of data.

```
+---------+--------+---------------+
| RadioID | NodeID | SourceRadioID |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| R0      |      1 |               |
| R1      |      1 |               |
| R2      |      1 |               |
| R3      |      1 |               |
| R4      |      1 |               |
| R5      |      2 |               |
| R6      |      2 |               |
| R7      |      2 | R0            |
| R8      |      2 |               |
| R9      |      2 |               |
| R10     |     11 |               |
| R11     |     11 | R9            |
| R12     |     11 |               |
| R13     |     11 |               |
+---------+--------+---------------+
```

What I need to do is to write a method that returns a list of `NodeID`. example,

```
List<int> dependentNode = GetChildNode(1); // int ParentNode
```

My expected results are NodeIDs: `2 and 11`.

`NodeID = 2` is included because there is a `RadioID  = R7` that is connected to `RadioID = R0` which belongs to `NodeID = 1`.

`NodeID = 11` is also included because `RadioID = R11` is connected to `Radio = R9` which belongs to `NodeID = 2` (*which is also connected to `NodeID = 1`*).

I lookup this article but I always get `StackOverFlowException`

- [Rendering a hierarchy using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758162/rendering-a-hierarchy-using-linq)

Here's the full code:

```
public class RadioEntity
{
    public string RadioID { get; set; }
    public int NodeID { get; set; }
    public string SourceRadioID { get; set; }
}

public class SampleDemo
{
    public void SampleMethod()
    {

        Func<int, int,List<int>> GetChildNode = null;
        GetChildNode = (x, y) =>
            {
                return (from _x in GetRadio()
                        where (GetRadio().Where(i => i.NodeID == x).Select(i => i.RadioID)).Contains(_x.RadioID)
                        from _y in new[] { _x.NodeID }.Union(GetChildNode(_x.NodeID, y + 1))
                        select _y).ToList<int>();
            };

        var _res = GetChildNode(1, 0);

    }

    public List<RadioEntity> GetRadio()
    {
        List<RadioEntity> _returnVal = new List<RadioEntity>();
        _returnVal.Add(new RadioEntity() { RadioID = "R0", NodeID = 1, SourceRadioID = "" });
        _returnVal.Add(new RadioEntity() { RadioID = "R1", NodeID = 1, SourceRadioID = "" });
        _returnVal.Add(new RadioEntity() { RadioID = "R2", NodeID = 1, SourceRadioID = "" });
        _returnVal.Add(new RadioEntity() { RadioID = "R3", NodeID = 1, SourceRadioID = "" });
        _returnVal.Add(new RadioEntity() { RadioID = "R4", NodeID = 1, SourceRadioID = "" });
        _returnVal.Add(new RadioEntity() { RadioID = "R5", NodeID = 2, SourceRadioID = "" });
        _returnVal.Add(new RadioEntity() { RadioID = "R6", NodeID = 2, SourceRadioID = "" });
        _returnVal.Add(new RadioEntity() { RadioID = "R7", NodeID = 2, SourceRadioID = "R0" });
        _returnVal.Add(new RadioEntity() { RadioID = "R8", NodeID = 2, SourceRadioID = "" });
        _returnVal.Add(new RadioEntity() { RadioID = "R9", NodeID = 2, SourceRadioID = "" });
        _returnVal.Add(new RadioEntity() { RadioID = "R10", NodeID = 11, SourceRadioID = "" });
        _returnVal.Add(new RadioEntity() { RadioID = "R11", NodeID = 11, SourceRadioID = "R9" });
        _returnVal.Add(new RadioEntity() { RadioID = "R12", NodeID = 11, SourceRadioID = "" });
        _returnVal.Add(new RadioEntity() { RadioID = "R13", NodeID = 11, SourceRadioID = "" });

        return _returnVal;
    }

}
```

You can suggest if there is much better way to do it. Sorry Newbie here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are newbie dont be too clever with recursion and lambdas.

```
    public List<int> GetChildren(int id)
    {
        var nodes = GetRadio();
        var parent = nodes.Single(n => n.NodeID == id);
        var children = nodes.Where(n => n.SourceRadioID == parent.RadioID).Select(n => n.NodeID);

        return children.Union(children.SelectMany(GetChildren)).ToList();
    }
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

```
public List<int> GetChildren(int id)
{
    IEnumerable<RadioEntity> parent = GetRadio().Where(x => x.NodeID == id);
    IEnumerable<int> children = (
                                    from r in GetRadio()
                                    where parent.Select(x=>x.RadioID)
                                                .Contains(r.SourceRadioID)
                                    select r
                                ).Select(n => n.NodeID);

    return children.Union(children.SelectMany(GetChildren)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: how is this getting the childrens children?

Comment: just relax, downvotes are not a personal attack, they don't mean anything other than the answer given is not correct and does not answer the question.

Comment: ok, to get all the children just add .SelectMany(GetChildren) in the return, and you are done. Actually I forgot to add ToList() in the end as well.

Comment: @VitalyBashilov no, the asker is asking for a recursive select statement

Comment: needs to be the childrens childrens childrens children... :)

Comment: @Fendy he is asking for a better way to do it, in my opinion it is a better way.

Comment: @VitalyBashilov, how's it better? he has a hierarchy of nodes and he wants a linq expression to query the hierarchy, your solution is to ignore the hierarchy!?!?

Comment: if you have tried to run your code, it will give you an exception on this line: `var parent = nodes.Single(n => n.NodeID == id);` please do try before posting it as an answer.

Comment: @KeithNicholas I'm reading all the children correctly now, I don't see your point.

Comment: @JW웃 so it ends up basically what we started with in the question :)